# Aligning Multiple Column with \hline

Tags: align

I'm trying to create this. There are many aligned elements, such as the equal signs and the 25s, as well as an equal bar. I can get some of the elements written, but I can't quite get everything. Please help. Thanks! [image]

Answer (score 2):

The nasty trick is centering “Vertical method”.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor,array}

\newcommand{\redplus}{\mathbin{\textcolor{red}{+}}}
\newcommand{\rednum}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{
  r
  >{{}}l
  @{\qquad}
  >{$\color{blue}}c<{$}
  @{\qquad}
  r
  >{{}}l
  >{{}}l
  >{{}}r
}
\multicolumn{2}{c@{\qquad}}{\text{Horizontal method}}
&\multicolumn{1}{c@{\qquad}}{}&
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\hspace{-1em}\text{Vertical method}\hspace{-1em}\hspace{0pt}} \\
g-25 &= 113 &
  Original equation &
g & - 25 &= & 113 \\
g-25\redplus\rednum{25} &= 113\redplus\rednum{25} &
  Add $25$ to each side &
   & \redplus\rednum{25} && \redplus\rednum{25} \\
\cline{4-7}
g &= 138 &
  Simplify &
g &&= & 138
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]